# Corda contract to prevent a node from creating states

Tags: blockchain, corda

In Corda, how can we design a contract to prevent a certain node to create states of a particular type?ⁿ For example, node Student should not be allowed to create a QuestionPaper state.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the approach of **blacklist** project in the samples repository:
https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/blacklist

1. Your flow that creates the `QuestionPaper` state must add an attachment to the transaction:
   https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/blacklist/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/attachments/flow/ReachAgreementFlow.kt#L31
2. Your contract will validate that the attached document matches the hash that is hardcoded in the contract (otherwise the node can upload a file that doesn't contain the blacklisted `Student` node):
   https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/blacklist/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/attachments/contract/AgreementContract.kt#L33
3. Then you check that the `issuer` (an attribute in `QuestionPaper`) is not on the blacklist (i.e. `Student` node):
   https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/blacklist/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/attachments/contract/AgreementContract.kt#L53

Comment: Hi Adel. The student node can still upload a file that matches the condition set in the contract.

Comment: No it cannot; the contract will have a hard coded hash value of the correct file, meaning first you write a file that has the `Student` node as blacklisted, then you hash the file; the resulting hash you hard code in your contract, so if the student node tries to upload a different file (a file that doesn't contain it as blacklisted) the resulting hash of the uploaded file will not match the hardcoded hash and the validation in the contract will fail. It's all clear in the example and my answer.

Comment: Hi Adel. But the student node can upload a file that has student as blacklisted. So the hash will match the hardcoded hash and the validation in the contract will pass and the transaction will succeed and will create a new QuestionPaper state.

Comment: Validating that the file is correct is one step, but what's the purpose of the file? Read step number 3 from my initial answer; you read the contents of the file (the blacklist) and you make sure that the issuer of your state is not on that list. You must also have the `issuer` as a required signer on the `Create` command of your `QuestionPaper` inside the contract; this way the `Student` node can't set the `issuer` to `School`, because if it does; then the `School` will become a required signer as per your contract, and obviously the `School` node will reject signing a state it didn't issue.

Comment: So to summarize, your state should have an `issuer` attribute, your contract should validate that the `issuer` is a required signer, your flow should add an attachment, your contract will first validate that this is the correct file, second it will validate that the issuer is not on the blacklist.